# Is the normalization of a blowup of a LC variety again LC ?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose X has log canonical singularities.  If one blows up a subvariety Z and then normalizes, is the resulting variety X' again log canonical?

I reason as follows.  Given a resolution of singularities Y-->X' no exceptional divisor can appear with coefficient less than -1 because such a divisor would have to cancel an exceptional divisor from X'-->X since X is log canonical and Y-->X'-->X is a resolution of singularities.  But no such exceptional divisor can exist because X' is smooth in codimension one and so the center of a blowup won't contain the generic point of any exceptional divisor for X'-->X, as long as one assumes that the resolution Y-->X' is an isomorphism over the smooth locus.